# Are there any frameworks or libs which like ASIHttpRequest in Obj-c ,I wanna to achieve a sync http request

Tags: android, synchronization, asihttprequest

Are there any frameworks or libs which like `ASIHttpRequest` in Objective C? I want to achieve a sync http request. And I want to use it with the least API level of 8.